# Get first and last item in one query

Tags: python, django

I want to get the first item and the last item in Django.
My current code looks like this:

```
first = Article.objects.order_by('date').first()
last = Article.objects.order_by('date').last()
```

However, these are two queries. Is there a way to make one query out of it?

Comment: Unless the `Article`s are sorted acoording to some function, `.first()` and `.last()` can just return *any* elements, since in a database teh "records" are unordered. of course there is an order, but this order can shuffle by insertions, etc.

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to add the order_by function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a *union* of two querysets. Since these querysets are only evaluated when necessary, the individual ones are thus not evaluated, like:

```
qs = Article.objects.order_by('date')[:1].union(Article.objects.order_by('-date')[:1])
```

this `qs` will then contain two elements, so we can obtain the articles with:

```
a1, a2 = Article.objects.order_by('date')[:1].union(Article.objects.order_by('-date')[:1])
```

although personally, I think this only introduces a lot of extra confusion.

Given it is possible that the table contains zero, or one element, this even makes it a bit harder, in that case we need:

```
qs = list(Article.objects.order_by('date')[:1].union(
    Article.objects.order_by('-date')[:1],
    all=True)
)
if qs:
    a1, a2 = qs
else:
    a1 = a2 = None
```

But as said, also by [@JonClemens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582538/get-first-and-last-item-in-one-query/53582608?noredirect=1#comment94029210_53582608), the optimization will probably not be that large, especially compared with the complexity you introduce in order to read this.

Comment: Not sure how efficient this is though... trying it on a test database with dates, the planner chooses to do two sorts of the entire table... just to get two rows fort he final output... Seems that the OP if they're going to be doing this often should have the field with a DB index and perhaps use `Article.objects.earliest('date')`/`Article.objects.latest('date')` (or set appropriate meta information) here... but that's just a guess. (So more overhead keeping the index, but much more efficient getting the first last each time with complicating the code...)

Comment: @JonClements: well the "optimization" is that this is done with a single query, and thus the overhead of two "round trips" will be removed, but like said, I think typically a *single* query is not that much of a deal. Typically one aims to avoid the N+1 problem (not having to load *N* items with one item/query).

Comment: Okay sure - I get it's a *single query* but it's still doing the same amount of work so just pointing out (mostly for OP/other readers) that it's likely not going to be more efficient except saving a single round trip but I'm agreeing with you all this does is make it far less obvious what's going on...

Comment: Also - the behaviour between this and the `.first()`/`.last()` is that those methods will return `None` where there isn't a result, while the unpacking here will raise an exception if there's not two results to unpack... the other thing to be wary of is that the `union` will remove the second row where it's the same row as the first result causing the above again... so a `all=True` might be prudent to pass to the union...